# After changing VolumeID (Disk Serial), Android (Lineage OS 17.1) refuses to accept card and wants to format

Tags: external-sd, sd-card

I tried this several different ways using several tools. In the past I was able to do it just fine. When changing to a new serial (VolumeID, like ABCD-1234), Lineage OS 17.1 on a Galaxy Tab S2 refuses to acknowledge the SD card, and requires me to format it. Once I format in android, of course it changes the serial, and I'm stuck in the original predicament.

I put into Windows, formatted fresh, and then changed serial using tools like DiskGenius and AOMEI. But when I put it back into Android again, it once again demands I format the drive again. Which I can do, then it recognizes it again, then I take out, change serial, and same problem again.

I also cleared any flags, checked for errors, etc, and the card has no problems.

The card is a 128GB Sandisk card.The former card was a different Sandisk card.

I did this using a 512GB Sandisk card to a 1TB Sandisk card, and it worked fine in a different device (running a stock OS). But this tab on LOS 17.1 doesn't like it.

I also tried this:
My fine 1TB MicroSD from my phone (which is running Android 8.0), which also has the same VolumeID (serial), I inserted this into the Tab S2 on LOS 17.1 and same problem - it asked to set up. I put the same 1TB card back in my phone, and my phone recognized it again no problem.

I also tried taking the same 128GB SD and putting it into my phone from before running Android 8.0, and my phone recognized this one too without a problem.

It should also be noted I did the same thing into a different tablet running stock Android 11 as well, without any issues. Same card.

So, it's clear that my tab or LOS 17.1 are the problem here.

The reason I need to do this is because many of my backups and data are dependent on absolute paths which means that it won't work to restore the data from the old SD card.

How do I change the serial to the number of my choice (the serial from my old SD card), so that Lineage OS 17.1 recognizes the card without requiring me to format it?

Comment: May be because you are not using one of the [supported partition types](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-12.0.0_r1/model/Disk.cpp#387). See the errors `vold` throws in logcat when mounting fails.

Comment: `exFAT` is not a [partition type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type) but a filesystem. But I hope you understand what I meant.

Comment: Keep in mind that the process was this: formatted in Android when it asked > took out and put in Windows PC > changed only the VolumeID (Serial) > Then reinserted into the tablet (LOS 17.1), and it didn't recognize it again and wants to format again. So, it's using the supported partition type - Android created it to begin with. Also, the same card works fine in two other devices (Android 8.0 & Android 11).

Comment: the problem is not with LineageOS but with using different MicroSD Cards all under same UUID. LineageOS detect mismatch to previous MicroSD Card partition size and think actual MicroSD Card is therefore corrupt. Factory reset will solve it

Comment: @alecxs On the other two devices, I also used 3 different SD cards with the same UUID (128GB, 512GB, 1TB) and all worked fine on the other two devices even though all 3 had the same VolumeID (UUID). *(Also, I only used a single SD card on the LOS 17.1 device at first, and only changed the VolumeID of it. So it did not know that there was another device with the same UUID.)* Factory reset does not solve it.